# Is it bad practice to destroy and create records to deal with updating quantity?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

Basically, I have a controller action that deals with updating the quantity of a product in a users basket.

Initially, I was taking the new quantity minus the old quantity and creating that many basket item objects (and saving them to the database). If new quantity minus old quantity is a negative number, I would destroy that many basket item objects.

This ended up being a little buggy, so I refactored the code so that it would initially delete all the basket item objects, then create the new quantity amount of basket item objects.

I was just wondering if this cycle of deleting and creating records is bad practice for dealing with updating quantity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create the new entry in the database each time when quantity of the product is changed. Instead of this, use a field in the Basket table for the quantity.
Basket table should contains the fields like `id, product_id, quantity, user_id` Or it depends upon the association which you are using.

Comment: Ahhh I see; that sounds like a better solution. Thank you!